# Trying to host my netcore app and get this error 500.30, netcore app 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core

I trying to host my app , and when runs , I get error 500.30, i've tried everything in documentation.

I reinstalled the hosting bundle, restarted IIS, but nothing works. Can anyone help me with that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLkeR.jpg)

i've tried everything in documentation.

I reinstalled the hosting bundle, restarted IIS, but nothing works. Can anyone help me with that.

Comment: You can found error in application logs & enable logging in IIS.

Comment: The error page tells you what to try - try enabling `stdout` logging and check the generated logs.  .NET Core 2.2 reached End-Of-Life 4 years ago though, in 2019. Packages no longer support it. The hosting bundle you installed may be the wrong one.  The current Long Term Support version is .NET 6.

Comment: You can also try executing the web app directly from the command line to check any errors or exceptions. It's really time you migrated or rewrote the application to target a supported runtime though

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.